# link-time code generation seems to diregard compiler warning settings

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm working on a relatively large C++ project. Generally we have all compiler warnings ON, and "treat warnings as errors".
We also use 3rd-party libraries (source code), for them the appropriate warnings are turned OFF.

Recently I've tried to enable link-time code generation (a.k.a. whole program optimization `/GL` option for msvc), which effectively defers the actual compilation to the linkage stage.

The problem is that during this link-time compilation all the suppressed warnings pop up.
Is there a way to work this around?

Comment: Disable warnings when doing the final build with whole program optimization. Because you've been developing with warnings enabled (and trust the third-party code) it's ok :-)

Comment: Yes, the question is how can I disable them? Linker doesn't recognize compiler options (such as /wd<number>)

Comment: Don't pass compiler switches and options to the linker.

Comment: Fixing the warnings (and submitting patches up-stream to the relevant third-party libraries) would be *my* approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a workaround.

At least in visual studio 2k22 (17.8.3).

If you specify the warning flags to the COMPILER, then these warning flags are re-used in link time code generation.

For example - [makefile where I made change to do add these flags](https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/commit/0e8350b6bee549e35230a06ce50383d31209ae67)

```
ifeq (VisualStudio,$(findstring VisualStudio,$(ProjectPlatformSubdir)))
ifeq (-LTCG,$(findstring -LTCG,$(LinkerArgs_ExtraPrefix)))
CFLAGS  += -wd4701
CFLAGS  += -wd4702
CFLAGS  += -wd4703
CFLAGS  += -wd4706
CFLAGS  += -wd4789
endif
endif
```